# WP7 bluetooth file transfer

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to do something like the "Bump" file transfer that iOS and Android has on WP7?  I assume they are doing it with bluetooth, but I'm not sure.  Will this be part of "Mango" if its not in the current OS?

Comment: I believe Bump works without Bluetooth. I don't recall leaving on Bluetooth when I used it (over a year ago) from an iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Bluetooth API available to third party developers, even in Mango. You could consider using Sockets with the Mango toolkit.

Edit - Just took a look at the Bump [FAQ](http://bu.mp/faq) and it seems the information is downloaded from their servers.

> Q: How does Bump work?
>
> A: There are two parts to Bump: the
>   app running on your device and a smart
>   matching algorithm running on our
>   servers in the cloud. The app on your
>   phone uses the phone's sensors to
>   literally "feel" the bump, and it
>   sends that info up to the cloud. The
>   matching algorithm listens to the
>   bumps from phones around the world and
>   pairs up phones that felt the same
>   bump. Then we just route information
>   between the two phones in each pair.

Comment: You could also use location based sharing, such as used by flick+share http://flick.cloud8studios.com/

Comment: @Matt Sounds close to what I want to do, but I believe they are uploading the pics to their servers so they can be downloaded from there, based on peoples proximity to the sender.  Seems a little unsecure and overkill.

Comment: @Tyler in that case you'll need the UdpMultiCast in Mango to get what you want

Comment: @Matt I've never heard of UdpMultiCast, everything I found when searching made it sound like its for phone to pc communitcation.  Will it also allow Phone to Phone?

Comment: @Tyler see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874(v=vs.92).aspx It will broadcast to everythign on the local network - which could be other phones. Won't be able to test this until we can get actual hardward running Mango though as the emulator deosn't support it.